# TF14097: Cannot rename (MY PROJECT DIR IN SOURCE CONTROL) when it has a working folder mapping assigned to it

Tags: android, eclipse, team-explorer-everywhere

I want to change the folder name of my project in source control and locally but I got the following error

TF14097: Cannot rename  (MY PROJECT DIR IN SOURCE CONTROL) when it has a working folder mapping assigned to it.

and I try to change the working folder but I got the following error too

The new working folder mapping of (MY PROJECT DIR IN SOURCE CONTROL) to (NEW PROJECT DIR IN MY PC ) conflicts with the server path in the existing mapping of (MY PROJECT DIR IN SOURCE CONTROL) to (OLD PROJECT DIR IN MY PC)

Comment: explain a little bit more..

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error when trying to Unshelve changes.  To resolve it I went into the source control explorer, selected the folder it was annoyed about, right clicked and chose "Remove mapping".